# Anki cloze card do not work with LaTeX

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, anki, dvisvgm, dvipng

I am trying to get Anki to work with LaTeX.

I have a custom card type with the following header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\newcommand{\OO}{\mathcal{O}}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
```

and footer:

```
\end{document}
```

I have a cloze card in my deck with the following code:

```
[latex]{{c1::Test}}[/latex]
```

When I try looking at the card, I get a broken image icon, and below that, the following message:

> Error executing latex.
>
> Generated file: /tmp/anki_temp/tmp.tex
>
> Have you installed latex and dvipng/dvisvgm?

I am using Kubuntu 20.04. I have `texlive-full`, `dvipng` as well as `dvisvgm` installed. The LaTeX code used on Anki cards compiles without problems in TeXStudio. The problem is only present on cloze cards: basic cards are displayed properly.

There are several questions of this sort on this and other sites, however none of the answers there solved my problem.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thanks, but I already read the manual on the Anki website. Most of what hgst copied in their answer there is about Windows or OS X. The only relevant-ish part to me seems to be the one about path. However, latex and the other commands are already in the path on my system, thus I see no need to use the add-on mentioned there.

Comment: This must be something specific to Anki and/or cloze (whatever that is), right? Looks like it's not able to find your installed `latex`, or is invoking it with the wrong arguments, or something. At least if you can post your generated file (the `/tmp/anki_temp/tmp.tex` mentioned above) someone here could see whether it at least looks like something that could in principle be compiled.

Comment: Indeed, I agree that this must come down to some quirk of the way Anki complies LaTeX. I had tried what you suggested. The folder `anki_temp` contains two files: `tmp.tex` and `latex_log.txt`. The latter is empty. The former always contains the card Anki is trying to show at the moment. It looks like this:
`\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

Test
\end{document}`

Comment: That sample input file (assuming you quoted it literally: BTW you can also edit it into the question, where linebreaks etc show up) compiles successfully, so I'm afraid this is a problem out of the scope of TeX/LaTeX and more with asking Anki why it can't find the `latex` that's installed.